# WPF Databinding to a Dictionary<sting,List<string>> not updating after opening ComboBox

Tags: wpf, dictionary, data-binding, combobox

I have a combobox's `itemSource` property bound to a property of type `Dictionary<string,List<string>>`. This is so I do not need to create a large amount of properties in my datacontext file. For example, I have 2 ComboBoxes (CoBoA, CoBoB), and i have a dict

```cs
private Dictionary<string, List<string>> _itemSources = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
{
    {"CoBoA", new List<string>() }, {"CoBoB", new List<string>() }
};
public Dictionary<string, List<string>> ItemSources
{
    get
    {
        return _itemSources ;
    }
    set
    {
        _itemSources = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemSources));
    }
}

// initialise populate itemSources in constructor or elsewhere
```

```xml
<!-- CoBoA -->
<ComboBox IsEditable="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSources[CoBoA]}"/>
<!-- CoBoB -->
<ComboBox IsEditable="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSources[CoBoB]}"/>
```

When you open the ComboBox, any new items added to the List<string> value in the dictionary (after opening the ComboBox) will not show up - though OnPropertyChanged() was called. However, if you add items to the List<string> value before you open the ComboBox, they'll show up.

#### I setter doesn't run whatsoever.

I put breakpoints on the setter and theyre never triggered. This may be wrong, but I believe this also occurs on `List<T>`s. Because of this, I tried to call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(<PropertyName>))` when I update the dict with new values for the `List<string>` key. That didn't work. I'd get the same behaviour as before.

Incase it's important, I update the dict like so

```cs
ItemSources[key].Add(value);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can provide more info about my specific solution if need be.

Comment: The collection you bound the combobox to (the `List<string>`) is not observable. Change it to `ObservableCollection<string>` and it should work

Comment: Yep. That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, are you want to update the items of `ComboBox` when the `List<string>` changes?

You should use `ObservableCollection` not `List`. `ObservableCollection` can notify the items changes to Binding target.

And `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation is notifies that "this property's reference or value has changed", not that "the instance of this property has changed".
So you update dictioanry items will not notify anything. If you need notify the dictionary inner changes to binding target after shown, see Ferid's answer.
Otherwise, if the ComboBox are static binding to existed dictionary item, you just need a simple auto property, and set `Mode=OneTime` on `Binding` (`ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSources[CoBoA], Mode=OneTime}"`) to avoid potential memory leak issues.

Comment: Yep. Using `Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<string>>` worked. Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are not inherently observable, which means changes to the dictionary might not automatically trigger updates in the UI. Consider using an ObservableDictionary.

You can implement it or find third-party implementations that provide notifications for dictionary changes. When items are added or removed from the dictionary, these notifications can trigger updates in the UI.

Also, you can use ObservableCollection to store the dictionary, you can monitor the CollectionChanged event to detect changes in the dictionary.

Finally, in your XAML, bind the ComboBox like this:

```
<ComboBox Name="myComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDictionaryCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Key" SelectedValuePath="Value" />
```

Make sure that your DataContext is set to an instance of MyViewModel, and updates to the ObservableCollection will trigger updates in the ComboBox. Also, ensure that any changes you make to the dictionary within the ViewModel correctly update the ObservableCollection.

Try it and let me know is it working.

Comment: There is no data binding to a dictionary. If you take a closer look at the question, you see expressions like `{Binding ItemSources[CoBoA]}`, which is a Binding to the value of an element of a dictionary, i.e. a `List<string>`. This should simply be replaced by an `ObservableCollection<string>`.

Comment: You are using dictionary and read I what I wrote and it does not matter if you are using a specific value you are using dictionary collection.

Comment: It was not me who was asking the question. And you don't seem to understand what `Binding ItemSources[CoBoA]}` means. It is *not* a binding to a Dictionary.

Comment: I apologize because I didn’t see that you asked the question and on the other side I exacly know what is happening because I saw the same thing in a solution and the point was to give a focus on observable collections and that is it(in short because I can not elaborate what I want to say). @Clemens